# jQuery .each() Works Only on the Last Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I am trying to create a list of videos to be fetched via YouTube. Here is my HTML:

```
  <ul class="videos-list">
<li>
  <a href="#" class="vid_thumb">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x90&amp;text=Loading+.+.+." class="yt_thumb" data-url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/f_JRZI9o49w?v=2&amp;alt=jsonc" alt="" />
  <span class="duration">Loading...</span></a>
  <h5><a href="#"></a></h5>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="vid_thumb">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120x90&amp;text=Loading+.+.+." class="yt_thumb" data-url=
  "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/uHUHFthr2QA?v=2&amp;alt=jsonc" alt="" />
  <span class="duration">Loading...</span></a>
  <h5><a href="#"></a></h5>
</li>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    /**
     * Set up JSON parsing for video pages
     */
    $("a.vid_thumb").each(function(i) {
        $this = $(this);
        feed_url = $this.children(".yt_thumb").attr("data-url");
        $.getJSON(feed_url, function(json) {
            $title = json.data.title;
            $url = json.data.player.
        default;
            $thumb = json.data.thumbnail.sqDefault;
            $duration = json.data.duration;
            $likes = json.data.likeCount;
            $views = json.data.viewCount;
            $this.next("h5").html("<a href=" + $url + ">" + $title + "</a>");
            $this.children(".duration").html($duration);
            $this.children(".yt_thumb").attr("src", $thumb);
            $this.next("span.view_count").html($views + " Views");
            $this.next("span.upload_date").html($likes + " Likes");
        });
    });
});
```

The script is supposed to work on all anchors with class name "vid_thumb". But it works only on the last element.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJNAa/ Am I missing something?

Comment: I added an alert after the point where the duration is checked, it seems your code fills the first duration also in the second div. and replaces it after with the correct time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is a classic Javascript mistake.

If you omit the `var` keyword when declaring a variable, it will be created as a *global variable*.

What you want are variables local to each function, so make sure to prefix them all with `var`.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FXmR/) for an updated and working jsFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix your variables with the `var` keyword, otherwise they are global:

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Bm2VG/1/)**